# React Native Redux Shopping Cart App Problems

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am trying to make an application that allows the user to select **'Add to cart'** within my **DetailsComponent.js** page. I am currently updating an array within my store named 'cart' with ids that correspond to products within a products array within the store. I have checked the debugger and the product id is correctly being added to the cart array.
I am using the following code to show products on my cart page that match the product ids in my cart but my cart is currently showing nothing.

**CartComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
import { removeCart } from '../redux/ActionCreators';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        products: state.products,
        cart: state.cart
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =  dispatch => ({
    removeCart: (id) => dispatch(removeCart(id))
});

class CartScreen extends Component {
    
    render() {

        const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
            return(
               <ListItem 
                    key={index}    
                    bottomDivider
                >
                   <ListItem.Content>
                        <ListItem.Title>
                            {item.name}
                        </ListItem.Title>
                        <ListItem.Subtitle>
                            {item.quantity} chargers: ${item.price}
                        </ListItem.Subtitle>
                   </ListItem.Content>
                   
               </ListItem>
            );
        }
        if (this.props.cart.isLoading) {
            return(
                <Loading />
            )
        }
        else if (this.props.cart.errMess) {
            return(
                <Text>{this.props.cart.errMess}</Text>
            )
        }
        else {
            return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Cart
                </Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => this.props.cart.cart.some(el => el === product.id))}
                    renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />
            </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartScreen);
```

I have included my other files for more information.

I have different DropDownPicker values that correspond to the product IDs in my redux store. These items in the store have quantity and price values to be used in the CartComponent.js.

**DetailsComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Button, FlatList, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
import { postCart } from '../redux/ActionCreators';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        chargers: state.chargers,
        utensils: state.utensils,
        orders: state.orders,
        products: state.products
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    postCart: (id) => dispatch(postCart(id))
})

class DetailsScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            itemId: '',
            orderAmount: '',
            orderPrice: ''
        }
    }

    addToCart(id) {
        this.props.postCart(id);
    }

    render() {
        const categoryName = this.props.route.params.categoryName;
        const productId = this.props.route.params.menuId;                  
        const item = this.props[categoryName][categoryName][productId];
        if (categoryName === "chargers") {
            if (productId === 0) {
                var amounts = [
                    {label: '50', value: '1'},
                    {label: '100', value: '2'},
                    {label: '150', value: '3'},
                    {label: '200', value: '4'},
                    {label: '250', value: '5'},
                    {label: '300', value: '6'},
                    {label: '350', value: '7'},
                    {label: '400', value: '8'},
                    {label: '450', value: '9'},
                    {label: '500', value: '10'},
                    {label: '550', value: '11'},
                    {label: '600', value: '12'},
                ];
            }
            else if (productId === 1) {
                var amounts = [
                    {label: '50', value: '14'},
                    {label: '100', value: '15'},
                    {label: '150', value: '16'},
                    {label: '200', value: '17'},
                    {label: '250', value: '18'},
                    {label: '300', value: '19'},
                    {label: '350', value: '20'},
                    {label: '400', value: '21'},
                    {label: '450', value: '22'},
                    {label: '500', value: '23'},
                    {label: '550', value: '24'},
                    {label: '600', value: '25'},
                ];
            }
            else if (productId === 2) {
                var amounts = [
                    {label: '50', value: '27'},
                    {label: '100', value: '28'},
                    {label: '150', value: '29'},
                    {label: '200', value: '30'},
                    {label: '250', value: '31'},
                    {label: '300', value: '32'},
                    {label: '350', value: '33'},
                    {label: '400', value: '34'},
                    {label: '450', value: '35'},
                    {label: '500', value: '36'},
                    {label: '550', value: '37'},
                    {label: '600', value: '38'},
                ];
            }
        }
        else if (categoryName === "utensils") {
            if (productId === 0) {
                var amounts = [
                    {label: '1', value: '40'},
                    {label: '2', value: '41'},
                    {label: '3', value: '42'},
                    {label: '4', value: '43'},
                    {label: '5', value: '44'},
                ];
            }
            else if (productId === 1) {
                var amounts = [
                    {label: '1', value: '46'},
                    {label: '2', value: '47'},
                    {label: '3', value: '48'},
                    {label: '4', value: '49'},
                    {label: '5', value: '50'},
                ];
            }
                
        }
        
        
        if (this.props[categoryName].isLoading) {
            return(
                <Loading />
            )
        }
        else if (this.props[categoryName].errMess) {
            return(
                <Text>
                    {this.props[categoryName][categoryName].errMess}
                </Text>
            )
        }
        else {
            return(
                <ScrollView>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        {item.name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {item.category}
                    </Text>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.image}
                            source={{uri: baseUrl + item.image}}
                        />
                        <DropDownPicker
                            items={amounts}
                            defaultNull
                            placeholder="Select amount"
                            containerStyle={{height: 40, width: 100}}
                            itemStyle={{
                                justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                            }}
                            onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
                                itemId: this.props.products.products[item.value].id,
                                orderAmount: this.props.products.products[item.value].quantity,
                                orderPrice: this.props.products.products[item.value].price
                            })}
                        />
                    </View>
                    
                    <Text>
                        {item.description}
                    </Text>
                    
                    <Text>
                        Your order is {this.state.orderAmount} {this.props[categoryName][categoryName][productId].name} chargers for ${this.state.orderPrice}
                    </Text>
                    <Button
                        title='Add to Cart'
                        color="#f194ff"
                        onPress={() => this.addToCart(this.state.itemId)}
                    />
    
                </ScrollView>
            )
        }
        
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        resizeMode: "contain",
          height: 200,
          width: 200
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 32,
    },
  });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DetailsScreen);
```

The following code samples are my redux files. I have simplified them with only the cart information for readability.

**ActionCreators.js**

```
export const fetchCart = () => (dispatch) => {
    
    dispatch(cartLoading());

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'cart')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(cart => dispatch(addCart(cart)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(cartFailed(error.message)));
};

export const cartLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.CART_LOADING
});

export const cartFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.CART_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const postCart = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    const newCart = {
        id: id
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(addToCart(newCart));
    }, 2000);
};

export const addToCart = (cart) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: cart
});

export const addCart = (id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_CART,
    payload: id
});

export const removeCart = (id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.REMOVE_CART,
    payload: id
});
```

**ActionTypes.js**

```
export const POST_CART = 'POST_CART';
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART';
export const ADD_CART = 'ADD_CART';
export const REMOVE_CART = 'REMOVE_CART';
export const CART_LOADING = 'CART_LOADING';
export const CART_FAILED = 'CART_FAILED';
```

**cart.js**

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const cart = (
    state = { 
        isLoading: true,
        errMess: null,
        cart:[]
    }, 
    action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ActionTypes.ADD_CART:
                return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, cart: action.payload};
    
            case ActionTypes.CART_LOADING:
                return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, cart: []};
    
            case ActionTypes.CART_FAILED:
                return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload};

            case ActionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
                var newCart = action.payload;
                return {...state, cart: state.cart.concat(newCart) };
    
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

The following is my db.json file. I have input one item into the cart array for testing but it also does not show up in the cart. Have also simplified this file to only show a few products for readability.

```
"products": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "chargers",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 0,
            "price": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 40
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 100,
            "price": 70
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 150,
            "price": 110
        }
    ],
    "cart": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm this piece of code works as intended `this.props.products.products`
Also please check if the filtering logic in the data prop of Flatlist is working as expected.

Comment: How can I check if it works as expected?

Comment: I found that doing
data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => product.name.includes('e'))}
works to show me data in my flatlist but doing 
data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => product.id.includes('1'))}
does not work.

It's like it isn't recognising the id field in my array of objects

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the following:

```
export const addToCart = (id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: id
});
```

Not sure if this was causing any issues but I changed it to id for safe measure.

This is what was causing the main issue, I needed to use el.id to specify that's what I was comparing with in the data.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => this.props.carts.carts.some(el => el.id === product.id))}
  renderItem={renderMenuItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
/>
```